# CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE for X509 certificate C_CreateObject

Tags: pkcs#11

I get a TEMPLETE_INCOMPLETE while creating a X509 cert object.

FILL_ATTR(cert_templ[0], CKA_TOKEN, &_true, sizeof(_true));

FILL_ATTR(cert_templ[1], CKA_VALUE, contents, contents_len);

FILL_ATTR(cert_templ[2], CKA_CLASS, &clazz, sizeof(clazz));

FILL_ATTR(cert_templ[3], CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, &cert_type, sizeof(cert_type));

FILL_ATTR(cert_templ[4], CKA_PRIVATE, &_false, sizeof(_false));

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the minimal attribute template for certificate object creation that works for me in [Pkcs11Admin](https://pkcs11admin.net/) application:

```csharp
var certificateAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>()
{
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, false),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_MODIFIABLE, true),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, privKeyAttributes[0].GetValueAsString()),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, CKC.CKC_X_509),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SUBJECT, x509Certificate.SubjectDN.GetDerEncoded()),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ID, privKeyAttributes[1].GetValueAsByteArray()),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ISSUER, x509Certificate.IssuerDN.GetDerEncoded()),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, new DerInteger(x509Certificate.SerialNumber).GetDerEncoded()),
    new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_VALUE, x509Certificate.GetEncoded())
};
```

It's written in C# but I'm sure you'll be able to read and understand it.

Note that you will most likely need to parse the certificate in order to get correct values of `CKA_SUBJECT`, `CKA_ISSUER` and `CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER` attributes.

Note also that `CKA_LABEL` and `CKA_ID` attributes are usually set to the same values as are set on corresponding private key object. This way certificate object gets "paired" with the private key object.

Comment: Thanks @jariq. If I do not have OPENSSL installed to parse the cert, it appears I can send it empty (default) values for CKA_SUBJECT, CKA_ISSUER and CKA_ID.